# Does disabling visual effects improve performance?

Tags: windows-10

Does disabling [visual effects](https://gyazo.com/6ebbee5bdee9ac33faf1edcf65adedf1) improve performance? Or is it just a myth? Or is the effect minimal?
I'm on Windows 10 by the way.

Comment: It improves user interface responsiveness for machines that would otherwise struggle with displaying those effects. It does not improve performance of running programs while no user interface interaction is going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, of course. Not spending CPU time for those visualization tasks frees the processor up for some other more useful tasks. However the improvement is usually minimal and not noticeable, unless you're running some highly CPU-intensive tasks like rendering or simulations. Some of those things are accelerated by the GPU so the improvement in CPU performance is even less

Comment: And if the OS is even remotely well designed, it'll suspend or even backburner those visualisation effects while something that's making serious demands of the GPU is running *anyway*.